# How can I create a complication without the need of creating a watchface?

Tags: wear-os

I'd like to create a complication which does not need data but to be used for doing actions in one-tap. That said, I cannot find how to create a complication behavior without the need of creating a watchface for it. Can you suggest me anything?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a Wear app with a complication provider to also include a watch face; they're completely separate components. The official [documentation for creating a provider](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-providers/exposing-data-complications) is probably your best place to start; if you have any experience developing for Android, that should be enough to get you going.